# How to send a char or int to a method which require string a s parameter in Java?

Tags: java, string, input, casting, char

I want to send a space, char and int as input to a method which requires string as parameter. Is it possible to do that? if possible, how to do that?

Comment: search for `java primitive parsing`

Comment: just append quotes to char or int, then give it as a param => x + "";

Comment: Post the function definition, if can please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.valueOf(char c)
String.valueOf(int i)
```

All are valid APIs provided by String class. Using `String.valueOf()` is a more clean and efficient option than `+ ""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change char/int into String by simple appending quotes `x + ""`. And then in method you can use `parseInt()` to get integer back.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert char or  integer to string using tostring method. For example

```
    String temp = Character.toString(charData);
```

for integer u can use the same thing

```
           String temp = Integer.toString(i);
```

or if you want to combine int , char n space as single string you can use concatenation as suggested by juvanis.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No need fro `toString()` method, If you are not validating the argument to send, then shut your eyes and send any thing to the method.

```
int i=12;
char ch='a';
String st="Hello";
//or any primitive data type
myStringAccepter(""+i);
myStringAccepter(""+ch);
myStringAccepter(st);

...
public void myStringAccepter(String str) {
   System.out.println("You passed: "+str);
}
```

if you care of the argument to pass then first validate it before passing to method.